# Installing a package from private pypi in zc.buildout

Tags: python, reportlab, buildout

I'm trying to install a python package from the private reportlab pypi server using zc.buildout.

When I install using the instructions provided on their own site, then it installs without problem. http://www.reportlab.com/reportlabplus/installation/

If however I install using zc.buildout, I keep getting `Couldn't find distributions for 'rlextra'`. I added their pypi repo to `find-links`, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.

My buildout config:

```
[buildout]
versions = versions
include-site-packages = false
extensions = mr.developer
unzip = true

find-links = https://[user]:[pass]@www.reportlab.com/pypi

parts =
    python
    django
    compass-config

auto-checkout = *

eggs =
    ...
    rlextra
    ...

... etc.
```

**Edit**: I should point out that I did in the end do a manual download of the package, and using it in my buildout as a develop package. Even though this solves the immediate issue, I would still like to know why my original setup is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing in the PyPI main link for the `find-links` URL, but `find-links` only works with the simple index style pages (which exist per package on PyPI).

For example, the `beautifulsoup4` package has a simple index page at `https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/`.

The ReportLab server also has simple pages; add the one for this package to your buildout:

```
find-links = https://[user]:[pass]@www.reportlab.com/pypi/simple/rlextra/
```

IIRC you can also add the top-level `https://[user]:[pass]@www.reportlab.com/pypi/simple` URL as a find-links, but being more specific saves on the URL round-trips.

Comment: Ah thank you! That works and the package is located correctly and buildout then attempts to install it. Unfortunately I'm getting a "Bad Marchsal data" error at this point, but that's a separate issue to this question, so I'll mark this as the right answer.